# Syntax error MySql and PHP near '@dfaf.fa''

Tags: php, mysql

I create a simple site for findID when I write the email.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user_id_test" id="user_id_test">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Find ID">
</form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

        //include database
        include 'include/db.inc';

        $emailUser = $_POST['user_id_test'];

        $findNewID = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail = $emailUser");

        if ($findNewID != "") {
            var_dump($findNewID);
            echo "$findNewID";
        } else {
            echo "Errore: " . $findNewID . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connessione) ."<br>";
        }

mysqli_error($connessione);

?>
```

I try to find ID for email: `dfaf@dfaf.fa` (it is in my database with ID 13) and I've this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@dfaf.fa' at line 1`

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ : see http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements or at the very least http://docs.php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string

Comment: `$findNewID = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail = '$emailUser'");` add single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about passing email as integer, pass it as string..

```
  mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail = $emailUser");    

 to

 mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail = '".$emailUser."' ");
```

This would work but it is not safe to pass parameters within the queries directly, make the sql injection safe first...

Comment: His question was why it is not working, I would mention sql injection too..wait

Comment: Thank you, now I've this error `Unknown column 'user_mail' in 'where clause'` :(

Comment: your column must be user_email :) ..check the database table

Comment: @ Danyal : Absolutely; if it didn't answer the original question I would probably have down-voted your answer ;-) It's just a common trope here on SO to nag for sql injection safe solutions and nag and nag,nag,nag ....because it's super-annoying. sql injections are in the top vulnerablity OWASP list for ...ages and yet you turn around and find the next entry-level coder learning the same stupid mistakes.

Comment: I hope that it's the last question :P , can I obtain the ID like a string or integer?

Comment: I agree @VolkerK :) I have mentioned the sql injection there in the answer thanks..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I'm not sure..I've this screen at the moment [link]http://i.imgur.com/0KyEHQQ.png 
I use your code :)

Comment: @PrincipeDade you are using result set as array

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo and for have a string result with ID? What is the code? :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use prepared statements to avoid this kind of errors and to avoid [SQL Inyection](http://php.net/security.database.sql-injection):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connessione,"SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail = ?");
if ( !$stmt ) { someErrorHandlingHere(); }

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $emailUser);
// same here: mysqli_stmt_bind_param may fail -> returns false

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
// same here: mysqli_stmt_execute may fail -> returns false

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $userId);
// and so on and on: error handling

mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

echo "The user id es: {$userId}";
```

Comment: If you do it this way (by default, without thinking, every single database query, just the same) you avoid some of the most annoying database security problems. Not all of them; there's never a silver bullet; yet it's a good start. see http://php.net/security.database.sql-injection and http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements

Comment: My code? I didn't post code. I just edited this answer to correct something.

Comment: I try your correct code and I've some error..don't worry :)

Comment: Yes, with this code you avoid Sql inyection, for example if somebody modifies the `$_POST['user_id_test']` = "1 OR 1=1".

With your code the query will execute `SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail = 1 OR 1=1` wich is correct, if you used prepared statements you avoid this kind of behaviour

Comment: Thanks @VolkerK, you are right, should add some error handling is this lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem (as has already been answered) is/was that you didn't mark the string parameter (the email-address) as a string literal within the SQL query. The MySQL server therefore interpreted it as an identifier (like a database/table/field name). And since `@` is an invalid character within an identifier the server reported the error you've posted, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html.

To mark a string literal within a query you put it (by default) in single-quotes:

```
 SELECT x FROM table WHERE y=z // compares the value of the field y with the value of the field z in each record
 SELECT x FROM table WHERE y='z' // compares the value of the field y with the string literal 'z' <- that's what you want
```

Anyway, here's an example (that addresses some other issues) using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) instead of `mysqli_*`:

```
<?php
define('POST_FIELD_MAIL', 'user_id_test');

if ( !isset($_POST[POST_FIELD_MAIL]) ) { // maybe the resource (...script) has been requested without that parameter?
    trigger_error('missing parameter '.POST_FIELD_MAIL, E_USER_ERROR);
}
else {
    /** that's you part you probably want in inc/db.php */
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');  
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // that's why there's not error handling code after each and every call to a pdo function/method
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    /* ***** */

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT user_id FROM user_tmplt WHERE user_mail=?'); // avoiding sql injections
        $stmt->execute( array($_POST[POST_FIELD_MAIL]) );

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if (!$row) {
            echo '<div>no such record</div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<div>user_id=', htmlspecialchars($row['user_id']), '</div>';
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $pex) {
        yourErrorHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is exposed to sql injections. Always sanitize or escape special characters in a string before using in a where clause. In this case wrap `$email` with quotes.

ie. change

```
$email to '".$emailUser."'
```

In the where clause.

Comment: About that 'unknown column' error, check your table schema and see whether you have a column named 'user_mail'.